# rstudio How to enable font ligatures in RStudio?

Tags: fonts, configuration, rstudio

I looked at [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) and I wanted to try it out with one of the listed supported editors. So I launched RStudio (Version 0.99.491 on a Win box) and set the font to Fira Code but ... nothing. So how to enable font ligatures in RStudio?

**EDIT:** The trick in the accepted answer below still works for RStudio Version 1.0.44. I still wish there's a simple button to enable it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I still wish there's a simple button to enable it.

Wish granted! We've just added this to RStudio 1.1.

[image]

You can try the preview release here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: Is there any way to get these ligatures to work within the plot window, e.g. for a `ggplot` axis?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but if it's possible it doesn't have anything to do with RStudio settings (ggplot2 fonts are rendered inside R).

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks! I changed the accepted answer to yours!

Comment: So, the comment of 2017. I use Rstudio latest from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/tags

There are no buttons for using ligatures. Where is this button?

Answer (score 8):

**RStudio now have a build in option for ligatures, you do not need these dirty hack any more, cheers!**

---

[OLD CONTENTS]

- Close RStudio
- Open `[RStudio dir]/www/index.htm` (If you are using a Linux distribution, the dir may be `/usr/lib/rstudio`, thanks for the comment of @CosminSaveanu)
- Add following code between `<head>` and `</head>`:

  `<style>*{text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}</style>`
- Restart your RStudio.

dirty but works.

Comment: Thanks Losses Don, your trick works (I corrected your path because in version 0.99.491 of RStudio, the latest at this date, index.htm is directly under www and not under www/rstudio) . I just wish there would be just a way to enable it directly in  a menu.

Comment: @greendiod you are right, i've changed my answer :P

Comment: I edited again the answer to move the `style` part inside `head`. But still, it should be easy to enable right from the user interface.

Comment: Also works with RStudio 1.0.143 on Linux. The location of the index.htm is in `/usr/lib/rstudio/www` for Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: @CosminSaveanu Hey, thanks for your comment! I have add the information you provided to my answer.

Comment: More detail on @losses-don's instructions for Mac: To find `index.htm` in bullet point 2, ctrl+click on `RStudio.app` in the `Applications` folder, then navigate to `Contents/Resources/www/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux then type in your Terminal,

```
sudo apt install fonts-firacode
```

Restart Rstudio then in Tools / Appearance / Editor Font: choose Fira Code and Apply.