# How can I use a proper arrow instead of a <- as an assignment operator in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, assignment-operator

It came to my attention, that some people use a proper arrow instead of the commonly used `<-` in their R Scripts. For example, you see such an arrow in the [RStudio Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0Th2QRZ7Rk) at 4min 8sec, see attachment. What do I need to change in RStudio to use this operator? To me, it looks aesthetically more pleasing than the good old `<-`.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Its still the characters `<-` but the font use ligatures to look like one symbol. See this existing question about enabling ligatures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548194/rstudio-how-to-enable-font-ligatures-in-rstudio. Choose a font that supports such characters.

Comment: You can use the keyboard shortcut alt-"-" to insert the assignment operator as well.

Comment: That is font-dependent ligature. They are still 2 characters, "<" and "-", but they are rendered by the font as if a single glyph.